# $resource instance's $save() wipes properties

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in a controller:

```
$scope.chart = $resource('/api/chart/01234').get();
// { name: 'Foobar', id: '01234' }

$scope.send = function() {
    $scope.chart.$save();
}
```

But after the user triggers `send()`, the only properties remaining in `$scope.chart` are those from `$resource` (e.g. `$promise`, `$save`, `toJSON`, etc…), the others are gone (no `name` or `id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why the instance's `$save()` wipes the instance, but using the class' `save()` works:

```
var Chart = $resource('/api/chart/01234');
$scope.chart = Chart.get();

$scope.send = function() {
    Chart.save({}, $scope.chart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be this:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

From [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) under the `Returns` section.

Comment: But the behavious I see seems to contradict that doc's example with the custom `$charge()` method. I understand that if I do `bar = foo.$save()`, `bar` will be an empty object, but why should `foo` *become* one too? Also, the part of the doc you're citing is about the opposite of what I encounter: it's about an empty object being populated afterward, but I have an already populated object that is wiped out.

Comment: You make a good point and I'm not sure why `foo` becomes empty as well. According the the docs `foo` should be populated with the data returned from the server. _Once_ it's returned. The only reason that I can think of for why your object is empty is that the promise hasn't resolved by the time you're checking. `foo.$save(function() { console.log(foo); }` should have `foo` with updated properties.

Comment: But I'm sure the object is populated before it gets wiped. So it's guaranteed that it's not the promise not being resolved yet. It has been resolved at some point.

Comment: My guess is that data methods on the object cause the object to be re-populated from the result of the call.  I'm not sure this is true, but if your API method is not returning anything when you call `.$save`, that might be the reason.